# Django model manager get queryset depending on lookup value

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have model and custom manager like this:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        super(FooManager, self).get_query_set()

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = FooManager()
```

I feel like this should be pretty simple but looked through documentation and "self" probably I missed something obvious. My question is **how I can return object/queryset depending on lookups passed during actual query?**

For example:

```
objs = Foo.objects.all()
print(objs, "Objects queryset only with status set to True")

objs = Foo.objects.filter(name__icontains='a')
print(objs, "Objects queryset with 'a' in name and status set to True")

objs = Foo.objects.filter(name__icontains='a', status=False)
print(objs, "Objects queryset with 'a' in name and status set to False")
```

I could imagine something looks like this sample:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        status = self.passed_lookups['status']
        queryset = super(FooManager, self).get_query_set()
        if status is None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(status=True)
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(status=status)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

queryset of manager class has no access to query passed to it.

you can do this by creating two query manager class for your model. see below

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        super(FooManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status=True)

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = FooManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

in your code you must use `Foo.objects.filter` when you want to filter status and use `Foo.all_objects`  when you dont want to filter status